# Adding a section to ContentRange GemBox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, gembox-document

I am trying to add a whole section to a particular occurence using GemBox.

```
Section section = new Section(documentModel);
documentModel.Sections.Add(section);

ContentRange backgroundCheckSection = documentModel.Content.Find("@@BackGroundChecks").First();
backgroundCheckSection.Start.InsertRange(section);
```

This code does not work since it cannot implicity conver a ContentRange object to a Section object. The goal is to add that whole section to where the variable @@BackgroundChecks appears. I havent figured out how to do it and was wondering if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to accomplish, but in order to insert the section's content range you just need to do the following:

```
backgroundCheckSection.Start.InsertRange(section.Content);
```

If you could provide more details about exactly what you want to achieve I could help you out further.

Nevertheless what I presume that you want is not to insert a section (this will split the section in which you're inserting into two so you'll end up with 3 sections) in the document, you want to insert only the content of that section into a specified place (where your placeholder "@@BackGroundChecks" is).

So for this instead of inserting `section.Content` you can iterate through `section.Blocks` and insert their content, like the following:

```
foreach(var block in section.Blocks)
    backgroundCheckSection.Start.InsertRange(block.Content);
```

After that you'll probably want to remove that placeholder:

```
backgroundCheckSection.Delete();
```

In case you do want to insert a section note that each section is separated with a section break and you can manipulate where the section starts with it (for example does it start on a new page or continues right after the previous section). You do this by setting the `section.PageSetup.SectionStart` property.